# Is it possible for an account in algorand to cover transaction fees for a transaction if that account it neither sender or receiver?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

recently I've been fiddling around **Algorand**.

I was going through the documentation & am wondering.

How is it possible for an **Algorand Account to cover transaction** fees for a transaction.

if it's **neither sender or receiver**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really an Interesting question,

I was also thinking something similar.

I actually found **Algorand do have a fee pooling mechanism**.

Before you do it you'll need to understand how Atomic transactions work.

For this you can check out [algorands documentation here](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/get-details/atomic_transfers/)

In simple words it ensures either a transaction is executed fully or it fails.

this allows to enable use cases like

- Circular Trading
- Group Payments
- Pooled Transaction fees
- Distributed payments

to execute and **atomic transaction** you'll need to group all the transactions & set transaction fees higher.

Like before you compose an object set transaction fees to something like 2000

```
txn.fee = 2000
```

and the transactions you want to make it free for would have to set transaction fees at 0.

```
txn.fee = 0
```

this will allow you to cover transaction fees for other accounts.

This is bit confusing but becomes much clear from this [conversation on algorands forum](https://forum.algorand.org/t/use-pooled-fee-in-an-inner-transaction/6502)